# Got error SSH_FX_FAILURE when download file from sftp

Tags: go

I use sftp library to download file from sftp to local drive. I use copy function to copy content from remote to local, but I got error **SSH_FX_FAILURE** when downloading many files. I dont know what mean this error. My go service deployed in kubernetes

```
for _, file := range remoteFiles {
    if file.IsDir() {
        continue
    }

    remoteFilePath := path.Join("/download", file.Name())
    remoteFile, err := ftp.Conn.Open(remoteFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        continue
    }

    localFilePath := path.Join(/"local/downloaded", file.Name())
    localFile, err := os.Create(localFilePath)
    if err != nil {
        remoteFile.Close()
        continue
    }

    _, err = io.Copy(localFile, remoteFile)
    if err != nil {
        remoteFile.Close()
        localFile.Close()
        continue
    }

    if err := ftp.Conn.Remove(remoteFilePath); err != nil {
        continue
    }
}
```